# Access Azure Development Server From VM?

Tags: iis, azure, iis-express

We are developing an application that we are deploying to Azure. It needs to work with a specific machine configuraiton. We we have this configured as a VM which developers can run locally.

However to test the VM configuration we need to publish to Azure and access it on a live Azure instance. Is there anyway to allow a local VM to get access to the Azure environment IIS on the developers machine? It doesn't seem to show up in IIS Express so I guess it isn't the same as a normal site?

Also is it possible to configure an Azure environment locally for testing. We want to host test applications for internal use and don't want them run on developers machines. We would like to run them on a server in the office.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003219/accessing-a-local-azure-app-from-a-virtual-pc-for-cross-browser-testing) will outline the general guidelines you could follow to enable your environment.

Windows Azure Emulator has its own load balancer simulator which bind to socket 127.0.0.1:81 (most of the cases, if port 81 is free). If the Azure project is developed with Azure SDK 1.3 or later with Full IIS enabled, then the Azure Emulator (for versions 1.3 ~ 1.6) will use local IIS to host the sites. IIS Express is not involved in any way with the Azure project. If you happen to run IIS Express, then most probably you have set up your web application project as a StartUp project in the solution. The correct way to locally debug Windows Azure applications is to use the Cloud Project as a startup project.

Please kindly update your question, if there is some doubt or confusion after checking [the mentioned related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003219/accessing-a-local-azure-app-from-a-virtual-pc-for-cross-browser-testing).

Comment: Thanks missed that. Sorry for the dupe. So that should mean I can also run Azure Emulator on a server without need for VS2010?

Comment: Well, yes, you can run it without VS2010, but you will have to use the command line tools to deploy your app.