# Make my Windows Azure Web and Services project available to my local area network?

Tags: iis, azure

I have a Project that runs on Windows Azure Development instance on a local development machine.

I have a **Web Project**  that runs on : `http://127.0.0.1:8080`
and a Services Project that runs on `http://127.0.0.1:81`

I want to make both of these project available locally on my LAN for development.

I've switched of the firewall and unblocked the ports 8080 and 81 from my firewall settings. but this still doesn't work.

Can you please help me out with this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a local Azure app from a Virtual PC for cross browser testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003219/accessing-a-local-azure-app-from-a-virtual-pc-for-cross-browser-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Brent explains the best solution would be to test this in the cloud (in a staging environment for example). There are plenty of examples that can help you integrate this in your build process. On the other hand, you'll be paying for this test environment, and this might not always be an option.

Allowing external access to your emulator is pretty easy, simply use netsh (which is included in Windows):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=10081 connectport=81 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=18080 connectport=8080 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Executing these commands will make your web project available on http://10.1.1.x:18080 and your services project on http://10.1.1.x:10081 (replace 10.1.1.x with your actual ip). Note that you might need to open the firewall on your machine to allow external connection to these ports.

Answer (score 2):

The local development emulator was not created to allow for external access to other services for in development applications. While there are some unsupport hacks that make this possible, the official recommendation is to run such services in the cloud and access them from there. I realize this can make debugging more difficult, but this can usually be addressed by either remoting into the guest VM that hosts your applications and/or enabling intellitrace (providing you have VS Ultimate). Alternatively, properly instrumenting your application can also provide the proper evidence to help in trouble-shooting any issues.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. I'm trying to debug the cloud services with my phone device (I dont want to use an Phone Emulator here, because I need a lot of Device functionality (Accelerometer etc etc). any easy way to access Cloud from Windows Phone 7 device for debug. any unofficial hacks would do too!

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for the "hack" the current one on Windows 8, AFAIK, is to go to (assuming default directory structure here):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric
```

and edit both:

```
IISConfigurator.exe.config
IISConfigurator.exe.express.config
```

and modify /configuration/appSettings to include an item  obviously replace "YOUR IP ADDRESS HERE" with your actual IP address such as 192.168.1.71. Here is an example:

```
<!-- these settings are for the devfabric scenario -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SetupCloudDriveDevPath" value="true"/>
    <add key="SetupMachineKeys" value="false"/>
    <add key="FixedSiteBindingIpAddress" value="192.168.1.71"/>
  </appSettings>
```

The debugger will still open to the origin 127.0.0.1:8* location but just replace 127.0.0.1 with your local IP address. Also, you will likely have to restart Windows 7 to get these changes to take effect and you want to edit the config files as administrator as they are protected.